# change div when i hover div inside other div using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML code:

```
<div class='container-1'>
 <div class='div-1'></div>
 <div class='div-2'></div>
 <div class='div-3'></div>
</div>
<div class='container-2'>
 <div class='div-1'></div>
 <div class='div-2'></div>
 <div class='div-3'></div>
</div>
```

and I need change div-1 in container-2 when I hover on div-1 in container-1.
I can't use JS.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, not with pure CSS.

But you can do it by hovering `.container-1`.

```css
.container-1:hover + .container-2 .div-1 {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
 <div class='div-1'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='div-2'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='div-3'>Hello World</div>
</div>
<div class='container-2'>
 <div class='div-1'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='div-2'>Hello World</div>
 <div class='div-3'>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah absolutely impossible with CSS, and if OP wants to select a sibling that is before your style change won't work anymore either. They'll have to use JS.